# Java 8: How to create map from list where Key is fetched from same class (empID) and value as object(Employee) itself?

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, java-8, collectors

How to convert from the list to map in Java 8 were in form of `empID` from within class and value as an object itself.

```
List<CompanyEntity> result = 
             ifEntityManager.createNamedQuery("findByEmployeeId", CompanyEntity.class)
             .getResultList();
Map<String, CompanyEntity> result1 = result.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(CompanyEntity::getEmployeeId, CompanyEntity::this)); ??
```

I want the second parameter in `toMap` as object itself. Could anyone suggest how to achieve the same?

I tried doing `Collectors.toMap(CompanyEntity::getEmployeeId, this)` but not able to get away from compile errors.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. "not able to get away from compile errors" is for sure not a reasonable problem description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Function.identity()` from `java.util.function`:

```
Map<String, CompanyEntity> result1 = result.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(CompanyEntity::getEmployeeId, Function.identity()));
```

Comment: @michalk yes, of course, you're right. Thank you for that notice!

Comment: or just `ce -> ce`